# Need to read values from 2 different web pages and put in the view of a third page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

The third view html should fetch the data from 1st and 2nd html.Can anybody help me with it..Thanks in advance

```
1) navin_test.html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="name">
    Name: Navin </div>
    <div id="more"> Click <a href="moredetails.html">here</a></div>
    <body></html>

2) moredetails.html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="comp">Company:Test</div>
    </body></html>


View in third HTML should be:
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> Name: Navin </td><td>Company:Test</td>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can pass data using query strings, you will need javascript knowledge to update parameters in anchor tag url. One other possible action is saving your data in cookie using javascript

Comment: Hi Ravi..Thanks a lot for your answer...Is it possible for you to be little bit more elaborative as I am new to javascript..maybe with a code snippet or some links.

Comment: I have this link for you: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111

Comment: another link to pass data by query string and javascript: http://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change third page to this

```
View in third HTML should be:
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> <div id="Name">Name: Navin</div> </td>
    <td><div id="company">Company:Test</div></td>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Get data from first page and then from second page

```
$.get( "navin_test.html", function( data ) {
  var value=$(data).filter('#name');
  var url=$(data).filter("#more [href]")
  $("#Name").html( value.html());

     $.get( url, function( data ) {
      var value=$(data).filter('#comp');
      $("#company").html( value.html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas.It was really useful.By the way If I dont have the second page...and I only have the first page.While parsing the first page I come across the link of second page like this( <a href="moredetails.html">here</a>).How can I make a third view where the content from the first page and the content from the link which I got from the first page be separated?

Comment: Vikas if you don't get me ..just let me know.I will try to simplify my question more.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rajeshwar changed answer accordingly.

Comment: Your code helped me a lot.Thanks a lot Vikas.The code you gave me needed little modification which I did and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is the correct answer to this.


<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("navin_test.html",function(data) {
  var value=$(data).filter('#name');
  $("#Name").html( value.html());
  var url=$(data).filter("#more").find("a").attr("href") ;

   $.get( url, function( data ) {
      var value=$(data).filter('#comp');
      $("#company").html( value.html());
    }); 
}); 
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <td> <div id="Name"></div> </td>
    <td><div id="company"></div></td>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```